# Getting a different root for http with php

Tags: php, http, document-root

Hi i am try to get the directory of the root folder in my program of that it can be a non-static directory.

Here is an example for my old link :

```
$oldfile="C:\\Users\\wongsh\\Downloads\\".$eid."_".$email.".pdf";
```

Here is what im trying to do :

```
$oldfile=$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."\\Users\\wongsh\\Downloads\\".$eid."_".$email.".pdf";
```

Unforunately `$_Server['document_root']` leads to `C:/wamp/www`.

Is there any way to fix this problem?

Comment: what is your expected output ?

Answer (score 0):

This is because `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']` returns

> The **document root directory under which the current script is
>   executing**, as defined in the server's configuration file.

So, `C:/wamp/www` is obvious.

If you are looking for appending only drive name. Then, there are multiple ways, one of them is

```
GetEnv("SystemDrive");
```

So,

```
$oldfile=GetEnv("SystemDrive").":\\Users\\wongsh\\Downloads\\".$eid."_".$email.".pdf";
```